# How do I turn the Nuka-World power back on? Glitch?

Tags: fallout-4

In *Fallout 4*, I got the "Power Play" quest, and I am at the button I need to press. When I do so, nothing happens; none of the power comes back on!

Is it possible I may have missed something?